# Error No. 2058 Plugin authentication_windows_client could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found

Tags: mysql, database, windows, sqlyog

MySQL has a plugin that allows user authentication against current user’s Windows credentials.  The plugin is `‘authentication_windows.dll’`.

I get the following error message from SQLyog:

> Error No. 2058  Plugin authentication_windows_client could not be
>   loaded: The specified module could not be found.

The “authentication_windows_client” is a `dll` that is supposed to be loaded on the client side. Actually I think that `SQLyog` is looking for an older `dll` which has been replaced by MySQL with `‘libmysql.dll’`.

How do I make SLQyog load the correct `dll`?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with mysql-workbench if it is clearly about sqlyog?

Comment: i open the mysql-workbench and it was perfectly working but not with sqlYog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlyog included clear text and dialog plugin but due to license issue the are not able to support window authentication plugin.

so either you may purchase the product or go for crack otherwise you cannot use sqlyog along side with mysql until someone is not cracking...

Answer (score 0):

**Error analysis**

Error information translation:

"Plug-in Cache - SHA2_ Password Unable to load"

The reason is that the SQLYOG failed to correctly parse the use of the mysql password encryption method.

**Solution**

Log in to mysql in the CMD command line (need to configure environment variable in advance), perform the following code

Connect MySQL sheel to localserver

> \connect root@localhost

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your password';
```

This is for the root account, if other accounts also have the same problem, modify to correspond to the username and password, execute the statement