# PHP compatibility with MySQL Windows Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, windows, connector

Getting the below PHP errors when trying to connect to MySQL using PHP and WNA.

I found an article from 2012 stating that PHP had no plans on implementing WNA compatibility.

Does anyone know if PHP ever implemented this feature?

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication
>   method unknown to the client [authentication_windows_client]
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client

Comment: This is for windows native authentication, not caching_sha2_password.

Comment: Then maybe this post would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51290248/1839439